# Do I use original x-data point matrix or design matrix when inputting parameters for train_test_split in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

When putting the paraments for the `train_test_split()`, I am confused whether or not to put the design matrix of my x-data points or the matrix that only holds the original x-data points.
They both work, and do not output any errors, however which one is the correct one to use when doing a training/testing split?

(xcoord is the original data and X is the design matrix)

i.e:

`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(xcoord, ydata, test_size=0.80)`

vs

`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, ydata, test_size=0.80)`

Also, what is the difference, if there is any?